# Jquery.ajax equivalent of curl command

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl, cordova

I am writing a Phonegap mobile app that needs to call an existing API.  The curl command works fine.  The API doc gives the following:

```
$ curl -d login=name@email.com -d password=SecretPassword -d site_key=biguglyhash https://api.example.com/api/v1/session.json
```

I have tried the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.example.com/api/v1/session.json",
    type: "POST",
    login: "name@email.com",
    password: "SecretPassword",
    data: "site_key='biguglyhash'",  // tried this 
    site_key: "biguglyhash" // and this
});
```

What I get from the server is:

```
{"message": "Session could not be created", "errors": ["Invalid site key"]}
```

I know the site key is correct since the curl command works with the same key.  I have tried putting site_key in a parameter of its own (see above) and as part of a "data" parameter.  Both seem to do operate the same.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not being blocked by same-origin policy, try

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.example.com/api/v1/session.json",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
       login: "name@email.com",
       password: "SecretPassword",
       site_key:"biguglyhash" 
    }
});
```

Comment: And if you do that with the data object, does it work? or no? You may need to serialize it as JSON too `data: JSON.serialize({ site_key:"biguglyhash" })`

Comment: It did work! But I had to put the the login and password into the data object also.